# Splitting string in a cell into multiple strings/cells after the nth comma

Tags: string, excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have an Excel spreadsheet with twenty or so cells containing stock tickers, each separated by a comma. Some rows have 8-10 tickers; some have upwards of 50.

For one of the websites I use, they limit the # of tickers that you can query at one time to 12. So for the rows which have more than 12 tickers, I would like to be able to have excel automatically (whether by running a VBA script or entering a formula in the adjacent cells) enter the 13<sup>th</sup> - 24<sup>th</sup>, tickers in the adjacent cell.

So, for instance, if I have in D1:

```
gs,fb,lnkd,nflx,aapl,goog,amzn,tsla,bidu,cmg,twtr,tsla,kors,pcln.yhoo
```

I would like Excel to keep the above string in A1 but then, put the following two strings in E1 and F1:

```
E1 = gs,fb,lnkd,nflx,aapl,goog,amzn,tsla,bidu,cmg,twtr,tsla

F1 = ,kors,pcln.yhoo
```

Also, as I mentioned, some cells may have upwards of 50 tickers, so ideally the code would be able to put the 24-36th tickers in G1, the 37<sup>th</sup> - 48<sup>th</sup> tickers in H1, etc.

I'm sure this is relatively simple but I'm pretty clueless with coding though I have rudimentary ability to use VBA. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4):

The following function does exactly what you asked for:

```
Function nextN(r As Range, s As Integer, n As Integer, Optional d)
' for a given range, split string by delimiter d (default: comma)
' then return at most n values starting at the s-th
If IsMissing(d) Then d = ","
splitarray = Split(r.Text, d)
If UBound(splitarray) > s Then
  If (UBound(splitarray) > s + n) Then lastVal = s + n - 1 Else lastVal = UBound(splitarray)
  For ii = s To lastVal
    retval = retval & splitarray(ii) & ","
  Next ii
  nextN = Left(retval, Len(retval) - 1) ' strip last comma
  Exit Function
End If
nextN = ""

End Function
```

If your long string is in cell `A1`, uou would put the following equation in cell B1:

```
=nextN($A1, 12*(COLUMN()-2), 12)
```

then drag the equation to column C, D, E, … and down to row 2, 3, …

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In case the comments in the code are not clear:

The first argument of the function is the cell with the "lots of ticker symbols separated by commas"

The second argument is the offset into the cell: an offset of `0` means "start at the beginning", an offset of `12` means "skip the first 12", etc.  In this case, I use the worksheet function `COLUMN()` to get the column number (B = 2), to compute the offset (if you want chunks of 12, then the offset in column B must be 0, in C it must be 12, etc. This formula computes those numbers on the fly for you).

The third argument is the (max) number of elements to return.

As you can see in the example, if you ask for more elements than there are, it will simply stop at the number that's available.

Comment: @user3133470 if this answered your question, would you mark this answer as "accepted"? It's the little check mark next to the question...

Comment: If anyone understands what it is about this answer that deserved a downvote, I'd be happy to hear it; it puzzles me...

Comment: +1 for the working answer

Comment: @floris - I have looked and looked but I cannot find anything to let me select your response as "accepted." This is what I see on my screen: http://prntscr.com/2dvf4k

Comment: Thanks. You are looking at the question (my bad, that's where I told you to look...) You need to look at the **answer**. Just below the "score" is a grey check box.